# Twilio: Hangup a call in an existing conference, ERROR 20404

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, twilio, error-code, twilio-twiml

Following situation:

1. Someone called my Twilio Number
2. Twilio requested my url
3. Caller gets into a conference (don't starts until a second person join)
4. TwiML makes call to a Mobile
5. The Moblie dont accept the call

=> no second Person enters the conference so it wont stop and the caller is stuck there.

My solution is to end the whole call if this happens, I already know where to place the endCall function so this is not my problem. The function looks like this (You'll find it in the twilio API too):

```
client.calls(accountSid).update({
    status: "completed"
}, function(err, call) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

My programm logic is fine, I see that this function is called at the right place but I receive this Error:

```
{ status: 404,
  message: 'The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC/Calls/AC.json was not found',
  code: 20404,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404' }
```

I already red whats at the moreInfo url but I disqualify
the solutions there. Maybe you have an idea whats the problem with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are almost all the way there. Your problem is that you are using your `accountSid` when trying to update the call's status.

You need to get hold of the `callSid` of the original call. You will find the `callSid` in the parameters that you receive in the incoming webhook when the person calls your Twilio number.

```
app.post('/calls', function(req, res, next) {
  var callSid = req.body.CallSid;
  // store callSid somewhere for use later

  // return TwiML to set up conference and dial your mobile number
});
```

You'll need to save that `callSid` and then use it at this point later when you want to hangup the call.

```
client.calls(callSid).update({
    status: "completed"
}, function(err, call) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Let me know if this helps at all.